# Draw and label two non-isomorphic graceful trees on 6 vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Draw and label two non-isomorphic graceful trees on 6 vertices.

-From what I learned in class; I know that, a tree with $n$ vertices is called graceful if it's vertices can be labeled with the integers $1, 2 , ..., n$ such that the absolute values of the difference of the labels of adjacent vertices
are all different. Although I can't visualize how to create a graph that would fulfill such requirements, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every graph with a number of edges $\leq 2$ is graceful.

Comment: Does that mean that any graph with vertices $\ge$ 4 cannot be graceful?

Comment: No, I did only state the trivial cases. The graph `1--4--2--3` graceful and has four edges.

Comment: See also [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GracefulGraph.html).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A tree with $6$ vertices has $5$ edges. The absolute value of the difference $|b-a|$  between numbers $1\le a\le b\le 6$ is an integer between $1$ and $5$. Each possible difference belongs to one edge and you can't use any difference twice. There are not many possibilities to try.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the labels of adjacent vertices. It makes sense to take the absolute value of a difference but I do not see where the actual numbers are coming from.

Comment: @D.Peterson You say the labels on the vertices are the first $n$ integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can take any number $n\in \mathbb N$. Then consider the graph

```
1 -- n -- 2 -- n-1 -- 3 -- n-2 -- ...
```

This graph with $n$ vertices will always be graceful.

Comment: So I see the pattern of the number increasing while the x in n - x increases. I do not however see what graph this represents.

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: If you have an example with $n-1$ vertices, can you think of a way of adding an $n^{th}$ vertex labelled $n$ to extend your tree? If instead you add $1$ to all the labels on your tree so they run from $2$ to $n$ can you find a way to extend that tree by adding a vertex with the label $1$?

---

You can also replace all the labels $r$ by $n+1-r$ before applying either of the above operations.